# Angular. Show slider of elements of array. Sometimes click dont work

Tags: arrays, angular, events, slider

It is necessary to show all the elements of the array in turn, if there is a click on "NEXT" and the index "0" is obtained, currently nothing is displayed if the index is "0", and clicking sometimes does not work. How to make a slider that shows all the elements of the array, even if the index is "0" and the click always works?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class CalendarDay {

  d = new Date();
  monthNames = ["1January", "2February", "3March", "4April", "5May", "6June",
    "7July", "8August", "9September", "10October", "11November", "12December"];

  index: number = 1
  i: number = -1;
  shMonth = this.monthNames[0];

  next() {
    this.shMonth = this.monthNames[this.index++];
    if (this.index === 12) {
      this.index = 0;
    }
  }
  prev() {
    this.shMonth = this.monthNames[this.index + this.i];
    this.index--;
    if (this.index === 0) { this.index = 12 }

    if (this.index === -1) { this.index = 12 }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>{{shMonth}}</h1>
<p>index:{{ index }}</p>
<button (click)="next()">NEXT</button>
<button (click)="prev()">PREV</button>
```

Comment: I corrected : "if (this.index === 13)  " on "if (this.index === 12) ". Still sometimes the click doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array goes from 0 to array.length-1. Your prev and next should be like

```
next()
{
  this.index=(this.index+1)%12;
  this.shMonth = this.monthNames[this.index];
}
prev()
{
  this.index=(this.index+11)%12;
  this.shMonth = this.monthNames[this.index];
}
```

See that you use the "reminder operator" -get the remainder of the division-, e.g. 13%12=1. This is the reason you add 11 (12-1) in the prev function

Comment: "This.next" waht it? It dont work. I see error this.next.

Comment: ::glups:: (sorry) change the this.next by this.index, I just corrected in the code

Comment: Than you. It work !!!!